# Bootstrap: navbar-toggler-icon not displaying

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to use the toggler icon to collapse and hide some navbar elements in my app. For this, I  copied the code found in Bootstrap's own [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) while adding some adjustments of my own:

```
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button> 
     <div class="col-3" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav  collapse navbar-collapse"
            id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" [...] >Some text</a></li>
            [...]
        </ul>
      <div>
```

However, when I run the web application the icon is not displayed; instead, there is an invisible button that, when clicked on, does not display the list items either.

Comment: have you include bootstrap css and js link?

Comment: So, the application is built in angular and I installed bootstrap via ```npm install bootstrap``` and saved it in the `styles` property inside the `angular.json` config file.